# Size of user defined class in c++

Tags: c++, class

Is there a method of calculating size of c++ class.
when i  create a object of this below class ,size of object is 24 byte.

```
class student
{
  student* pointer;
  char * c;
  student* AnotherPointer;
  class SubClass
  {
    int a,b;  
  };
};
```

and now removing Subclass from student class,i am still getting size of Student class object is 24.
why it is not changing??

```
class student
{
  student* pointer;
  char * c;
  student* AnotherPointer;
};
```

Comment: There was nothing more in the first versus the second. In the first you declared `Subclass` but did not put any instance inside your student class.

Comment: ***Is there a method of calculating size of c++ class*** `sizeof(student)` is the method.

Comment: A pointer has 8 byte (on 64bit system). Your class contains 3 pointers. That's 24 bytes. Declarations don't use memory

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a method of calculating size of c++ class.

You can use the `sizeof` operator to get the size of a class, or any other type. For example:

```
std::cout << sizeof(student);
```

> removing Subclass

Note that the class named `Subclass` is not a "subclass". It is a nested class.

> why it is not changing??

Because you made no changes to sub objects of the class. A nested class is not a sub object. It is in fact not an object at all - it is a type.